# Problems connecting to remote SQL Server using AutoIT

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, autoit, remote-connection

I am attempting to create a login mechanism by which you can access a remote SQL Server 2008 R2 database, in a private network, if the credentials are correct. I intend to implement the database at my work server and this program at a client which is in the same subnet as the server. Here is my code so far:

```
Func Login()

   $loginGUI = GUICreate("Login", 250, 150, -1, -1) ; will create a dialog box that when displayed is centered
   GUISetState(@SW_SHOW)
   GUICtrlCreateLabel ( "Input valid credentials to login", 40, 10,-1,-1) 
   GUICtrlCreateLabel ( "Username", 40, 40,-1,-1)
   Local $userInput = GUICtrlCreateInput("", 100, 37, 100, 20)
   GUICtrlSetState($userInput, $GUI_FOCUS)
   GUICtrlCreateLabel ( "Password", 40, 70,-1,-1)
   Local $passwordInput = GUICtrlCreateInput("", 100, 67, 100, 20, $ES_PASSWORD)
   Local $loginButton = GUICtrlCreateButton("Login", 40, 105, 70)
   Local $exitButton = GUICtrlCreateButton("Exit", 130, 105, 70)

   GUISetState()
   ; Run the GUI until the dialog is closed
   While 1
      $msg = GUIGetMsg(1)
      Switch $msg[0]
         Case $loginButton
            $user = GUICtrlRead($userInput)
            $password = GUICtrlRead($passwordInput)
            Global $loginCon = ObjCreate( "ADODB.Connection" )
            With $loginCon
               .ConnectionString =("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=192.168.1.30\SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=Test;UID="&$user&";PWD="&$password&";")
               .Open
            EndWith
            If ($user ="" and $password="") or @error Then
               MsgBox(48, "Login error", "Connection failed! Wrong Username/Password.")
               GUICtrlSetData($userInput, "")
               GUICtrlSetData($passwordInput, "")
               GUICtrlSetState($userInput, $GUI_FOCUS)
            Else
               $loginCon.Close
               GUIDelete()
               Main()
               ExitLoop
            EndIf
         Case $exitButton
            GUIDelete()
            ExitLoop
         Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
            GUIDelete()
            ExitLoop
      EndSwitch
   WEnd

EndFunc
```

I've also did the following actions:

1. Used SQL Server Management Studio to allow remote connections as well as the proper permissions for the correct user to access the database.
2. Used SQL Server Configuration Manager to enable SQL Server Browser and the TCP/IP protocol with the proper configurations to access the server.
3. Created a firewall Inbound and Outbound rule which allows access to TCP port 1433 and UDP port 1434 for the server and client (just in case).
4. Added `sqlservr.exe` and `sqlbrowser.exe` to the firewall allowed programs list.
5. Installed SQL Server Native Client 2008 R2 on the client PC.

I could connect locally to my database using the server IP but I get the following error when attempting to connect from the remote client to the server:

> *err.description is: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.*

Strangely enough, I could connect from the remote client using `sqlcmd`. I also have to mention that I am currently using my laptop to hold my test database. It's IP is assigned by the DCHP server from work and always remains the same.

Is my code incorrect or do I have to make additional server/client configurations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing that way I suggest to have client and server written in autoit. Put server to remote computer and make it interact with database locally. Than return what you want to client. This approach is more secure also. [Here is where you can start](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/98820-tcp-server-client-examples-to-learn-from/)